# Google Tag Manager Form - Thank You Page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to use google tag manager to have a tag that will fire every time the user submits the form and lands on the thank you page. In this scenario, I know an option is to use the Trigger: Page View, and then specify the thank you page URL in the conditional statement.

However, since this URL can be shared, I only want to track when the user submits the form and lands on the thank you page (not when the URL is accessed through other ways). What would be the best way to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

Why would people share the thank-you page? I can imagine sharing a form, but why would the url of the Thank you page get shared.

However, what you can do is track clicks on the button or link that submits the form.

Comment: Thanks for answering! The thank you page has other content such as subscribing to our magazine, or viewing our blog posts, so this may lead people to share the page out of convenience.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried tracking the clicks on the button, but then I'm unable to differentiate between forms that are submitted where all of the required fields are not filled out.

Answer (score 0):

I ll advise assuming you NEED to fire when the user gets to the ThankYou Page for X reason and CANT be done on the button submit click. 
Add a custom HTML tag with a trigger on the click of the form submit button (you can use build in variables such as Click Classes) and add a 'flag' on the session storage or a cookie (choose the one you are more comfortable with).
Then generate a trigger that fires on the Thankyou page AND has the flag on.

Example:

Tag when user submit the form:

```
<script>
storage.setItem('flagSubmit', 1);
</script>
```

Custom JS variable that checks if user has flag:

```
function(){
    return storage.getItem('flagSubmit');
}
```

If you need any more help just ask.
Hope it helps!

-- EDIT: add info

As you comment you cant detect if the flag is being saved properly so here is a code you can paste on the console that ll avoid you browser to exiting the page and allowing you to see if your click tag worked and registered on session storage you data.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() { debugger; }, false)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your clear answer - this was incredibly helpful!! For some reason, when I check my tag manager, the flag is showing up as undefined, and so the trigger is not firing on the Thank you Page. I followed what you said, and added the custom html tag (with the trigger on the click of the submit button ID), and added the custom JS variable. Then, I added a trigger to fire on the thank you page, and with the variable equaling 1. Any idea as to why the flag is showing up as undefined?

Comment: In a similar vein you could check the referrer to see if the user comes from the page with the form, which should give a  "close enough" result (users via shared urls will not have the form page as referrer) and does not require custom variables (you just need to check the built-in referrer variable).

Comment: @pdas i added a little more info so you can debug whats happening. Also, did you check manually on the console for the flag?